# Working with lage datasets in R (Sentinel 2)

Tags: r, bigdata

I'm working with more than 500 Gigabyte Rasters in Rstudio.

My code is working fine but the problem is that R is writing all raster data into a temporal folder, that means the computation time is more than 4 days (even on SSD). Is there a way to make the processing faster?
I'm working on a Computer with 64Gigabyte RAM and 1.5 Gigabyte SSD.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Sentinel 2, so it's complicated to help you on performance. Basically, you have to try to (a) use some parallel computation with `foreach` and `doparallel` packages, (b) find better packages to working with, or (c) reducing the complexity, in addition to the bad-answers like 'R is not suited for large datasets'.

A) One of the solutions would be a parallel computing, if it is possible to divide your calculations (e.g., your problem consists in a lot of calculations but you simply write results). For example, with the `foreach` and `doparallel` packages, observing many temporal networks is much faster than with a 'normal' serial `for`-loop (e.g., `foreach`/`doparallel` are very useful to compute basic statistics for each member of the network and for the global network, as soon as you need to repeat these computations to many 'sub-networks' or many 'networks at a time T' and `.combine` the results in a maxi-dataset). This last `.combine` arg. will be useless for a single 500 gb networks, so you have to write the results one by one and it will be very long (4 days = several hours or parallel computation, assuming parallel computing will be 6 or 7 times fastest than your actual computation).

B) Sometimes, it is simply a matter of identifying a more suitable package, as in the case of text-mining computations, and the performance offered by the `quanteda package`. I prefer to compute text-mining with `tidyverse` [style](https://tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html), but for large datasets and before migrating to another language than R, `quanteda` is very powerful and fast in the end, even on large datasets of texts. In this example, if Quanteda is too slow to compute a *basic* text-mining on your dataset, you have to migrate to another technology or stop deploying 'death computing' and/or reduce the complexity of your problem / solution / size of datasets (e.g., `Quanteda` is not - yet - fast to compute a GloVe model on a very large dataset of 500 gb *and* you are reaching the border of the methods offered by the package Quanteda, so you have to try another langage than R: librairies in Python or Java like [SpaCy](https://spacy.io) will be better than R for deploy GloVe model on very large dataset, and it's not a very big step from R).

Comment: thank you both for the answers! I will try out the suggested ways and then tell you which worked out best! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying the `terra` package, it has pretty much the same functions as `raster`, but it can be much faster.